# In vim, is it possible to turn my bibliographic keys into links?

Tags: vim, pandoc, bibtex

I write in pandoc markdown, which uses bibligraphic keys from biblatex that look like `@smith_foo_1999`, where "Smith" is the author name, "Foo" is the title, and 1999 is the year of publication. This corresponds to an entry in my library.bib file that starts `@article{smith_foo_1999`. I use [unite-bibtex](https://github.com/msprev/unite-bibtex) and [vim-pandoc](https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc), which both have great autocompletion for these keys, but what I'd really like to be able to do is to jump to my bibliographic entry in my library.bib file when I position the cursor over the key `@smith_foo_1999`, and press some key combination like `gf` or `<C-]>`. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a mapping in vim that opens the file, and searched for the selected word. Lets assume the following file structure:

```
.
..
img/
library.bib
markdownfile.md
```

a simple mapping could do most of the work then,

```
map <leader>bib yiw:e library.bib<CR>q/p
```

Place your cursor on the word, e.g. `@mybib_2015` and press `<leader>bib`.

This mapping will

1. `yiw` yank entire word
2. `:e library.bib<cr>` open library.bib in a new buffer
3. `q/p` will toggle search, and paste the aforementioned yanked word.

Comment: `bvwy` has a couple problems, I think. `b` will go to the beginning of the *previous* word if the cursor is on the first character of the current word and `w` will go to the beginning of the *next* word, not the end of the current word. I'd suggest replacing `bvwy` with `viwy` (visual mode, inner word, yank) or `yiw` (yank inner word). The latter will leave the previous visual mode are untouched, which may be relevant to fans of `gv` and similar commands.

Comment: Excellent addition! I didn't think about that.